# May I have the original behavior of the SO homepage please?

Tags: feature-request, homepage

With the new behavior of SO homepage - "interesting" and "hottest" tabs - I completely can't get what's going on and find this very inconvenient. When I refresh the page suddenly a whole ton of questions appears and then it turns out they are not all new - most of them are quite old. I find the original behavior much more consistent.

May I have an option in preferences for restoring the original behavior please?

Comment: You can get the original behaviour by using the link `http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active`, but it would be nice to have the "active" tab back.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thank you, didn't think of that.

Comment: I don't see a "hottest" tab.  I see a "hot" tab, but that was always there.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Aarobot: No, I just mistyped it. The point is I never used the "hot" tab and when I tried it I found it very inconvenient.

Comment: I even never go to the home page, I scroll through the tags I find interesting (they're bookmarked, so easy to find for me). That homepage has always been cluttered with questions I'll never be able to answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, click here:

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active

for background see:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Although ...

> When I refresh the page suddenly a whole ton of questions appears and then it turns out they are not all new - most of them are quite old

This was also true of the active tab; active means "new question, or new answer on an old question, or new edit on an old question."

Comment: Okay, I hope you will put the "active" tab back once.